# What is the way to store a date in a file?

Tags: java, android, io

I'm writing a small android app that lets the user pick a date and it shows him how many days are left to this date. Now I would like to store that date so that next time the app starts, it will keep the information. I was thinking it's probably best to save the date in a file, and my question is - how is it best to do this so it'll be easy to parse that date afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I speak from experience, The Best way to store a `Date` is to store it's UNIX Epoch time,

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("date", myDate.getTime() ); //getTime is a long (So store it as a string/long, doesn't really matter)
  editor.commit();
```

It'll save you the time/code from parsing it.

When retrieving the Date, just use the `new Date(long date)` Constructor or the `Calendar` class also has `setTimeinMillis`.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is probably to use the SharedPreferences:

Save in prefs:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("date", myDate);
  editor.commit();
```

Restore:

```
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
   String date = settings.getString("date", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it to application preferences. In your Activity you might have somethign like:

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
.edit().putString("date", myDate.toString()).commit();

Then you restore your date from that saved string.